# Is this normal on DVD/Bluray game discs?

Tags: xbox-360, ps4, nintendo-wii

Looking to my collection i have been noticed that there are some marks on the edge of the game discs, like glue or adhesive of the discs squeezed out from the outer edge, for example this Xbox 360 DVD-ROM:

[image: Edge of disk with area of concern marked]
<sup>Source: ZetaSuprema (question poster)</sup>

This is an example from a user with a similar case on my BD-ROM Xbox One games but is less visible; they looks like little bubbles of adhesive:

[image: Another example]
<sup>Source: Crop of original by BlitzDev54 via [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/eiq219/many_of_my_ps4_discs_look_like_this_is_it_normal/)</sup>

I should point out that it is not as if it were the exception, if not rather the norm, the majority that I have looked at have said marks to a lesser or greater extent.

Is this early signs of discs rot? I have not found nothing similar to this.

Comment: Can you limit the tags to one console? This is an interesting post but not suitable to be tagged with this many consoles.

Comment: Done! Sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know those are all just minor imperfections on the disc that are simply acceptable within the standard, i.e. they don't impact reading. I'm pretty sure they've always been there for these specific discs.

As for "disc rot": That's a phenomenon where the data layer is destroyed by changing it's physical attributes (and therefore making proper reading impossible). It would appear more like a king of stains (think of coffee stains), not visible deformations.